# Need help with a very specific Greedy Algorithm. Are there fast solutions?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, greedy-algorithms

i need help for a specific problem i have at work.

You have N number of rows in an array, each with some distribution of Numbers that range from 0 to N.Given an array of size 1000:

Row 1 might look like: [1,288,399,784,456,994].

Row 2 might look like: [4,784,123,8]

For each each element in each row, we take the mod 8, and obtain a distribution. In this case, it would be [3,1,1,0,0,0,0,1] , where each element represents the sum of that the values with that mod index. (3 elements had %8 = 0)

Row 2's distribution would look like [2,0,0,1,1,0,0,0]

We define the max of this list to be the 'size' of the row. In this case, the max size would be 3. The overall goal is to sum up the lengths of each row and achieve a minimum total size.

One Caveat is that we are able to swap any two numbers. In the original example, we can swap 288, 784, or 456 with some other index, lets say 581 with 784. Now, our distribution would look like [2,1,1,0,0,1,0,1], and we've successfully reduced the size of this row. However, any other row containing 581 or 784 must also be swapped, so we might have introduced a greater size to other rows.

For example, row 2 now looks like [4,581,123,8] after the swap. Now row 2's distrbution looks like: [1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0]. In this case, we might have decreased the size of row 2 as well! However, you can imagine that this might have just as well also increased the size of many other rows, so the overall size would increase.

I'm trying to figure out if there is a fast/greedy way to figure out what the optimal swaps are to minimize the sum of all the sizes. I'm lacking context on if there are any algorithms i should look at that solve this kind of problem. Please let me know if the clarification is necessary.

Comment: I didn't prove it, but I strongly suspect that it's NP-hard. I think Multidimensional Knapsack, which is [strongly NP-complete](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21865/multidimensional-knapsack-strongly-np-complete), can be reduced to it.

Comment: If $\pi$ is a permutation of $[0,N)$, $R_{ik}$ is the $k$th element of the $i$th row I believe you are asking $$\arg\min_\pi \sum_{i=1}^N \max_{0\leq j<8} \left|\{k : \pi(R_{ik})\bmod 8 = j\}\right|.$$